# Grails: Return 404 & show my 'Not Found' page for invalid id

Tags: grails

What's the best way to handle invalid ids in a Grails controller action?

When `MyDomainClass.get(params['i'])` returns null in my controller action I want the user to see my custom 'Not Found' page and for a 404 HTTP response code to be returned - I can't figure out the cleanest way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I've used the following in my controllers, where 'notFound' is a custom 404 page:

```
def show = {
        def referenceData = ReferenceData.get( params.id )    
        if (referenceData)
        { return [ referenceData : referenceData ] }
        else 
        { redirect(uri:'/notFound') }
    }
```

I also mapped the custom error pages in UrlMapping.groovy, something like

```
static mappings = {
   "403"(controller: "errors", action: "forbidden")
   "404"(controller: "errors", action: "notFound")
   "500"(controller: "errors", action: "serverError")
}
```

or

```
static mappings = {
   "403"(view: "/errors/forbidden")
   "404"(view: "/errors/notFound")
   "500"(view: "/errors/serverError")
}
```

[Grails Docs - mapping to response codes](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#mappingToResponseCodes)

Comment: I believe it's bad practice to redirect for a not found resource, at least for RESTful architectures.

Comment: @JoshDiehl is right. This implementation sends a 302 first, then a 404, you should return 404 right away.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT - I apologize for misreading your question.  the render method takes a status code.  So in the controller, if nothing is found, try

```
render status: 404
```

or

```
render view: you_not_found_view
```

or both (in one render call).

Comment: I have that already, but don't understand how I'm supposed to it to render when I can't find my domain object: `if (!MyDomainClass.get(params['i'])) { /* Then what...? */ }`. Doing `response.sendError(404)` returns a `404` alright, but doesn't render that error page - the user just sees a blank page.

Comment: I've just reread Grails in Action p. 331 and it says there are limitations to returning error codes - you can't provide content for the response and the content type will be `text/html`. Which I didn't know and confuses me further...

Answer (score 0):

Here's my magic formula for doing this.  Maybe there's a better way, but this one works and ensures the same 404 view renders whether you generate the 404 or grails does it internally (no controller found, for example).

First, create a View class that extends AbstractView:

```
class NotFoundView extends AbstractView {

@Override
    protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model,
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND)
    }
}
```

Next, create an error controller:

```
class ErrorController {

    def notFound = {
        return render(view: '/error/notFound')
    }
}
```

Now create your error view under views/error/notFound.gsp:

```
<g:applyLayout name="main">
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Oops! Not found!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Not Found</h1>

    <section id="page-body">
        <p>Nothing was found at your URI!</p>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
</g:applyLayout>
```

It's *crucial* that you use the <g:applyLayout> tag. If you use  your layout will render twice and nest itself.

Now for the URL mapping:

```
"404"(controller: 'error', action: 'notFound')
```

You're all set now to send that 404 from your controller:

```
def myAction = {
    Thing thing = Thing.get(params.id)
    if (!thing) {
         return new ModelAndView(new NotFoundView())
    }
}
```

This approach also lets you easily log the 404, try to resolve it and send a 301, or whatever you want to do.